# SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar returns null but raw SQL does not

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have the following code that uses the SqlClient.ExecuteScalar method to return an ID from a table.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmdContrib = new SqlCommand("SELECT ContributorId FROM Contributor WHERE Code='" + folderSystem.ContributorCode + "'", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    var contribId = cmdContrib.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Originally it was working but now contribId is null.  I tested the SQL in management studio after extracting from Profiler and it returned the ID as expected.

Next I added an additional command to retrieve an ID from a different table (Product).
productId is not null while contribId continues to be null.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmdContrib = new SqlCommand("SELECT ContributorId FROM Contributor WHERE Code='" + folderSystem.ContributorCode + "'", conn))
using (var cmdTest = new SqlCommand("SELECT productId FROM Product WHERE [filename] = 'bda00001.jpg'", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    var contribId = cmdContrib.ExecuteScalar();
    var productId = cmdTest.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I am sure it is something obvious and I'll kick myself for not noticing it, but for now I'm stumped.

Comment: What's your debug value for folderSystem.ContributorCode?

Comment: What value does folderSystem.ContributorCode contain? I'm leaning towards this being an SQL-injection sort of bug (eg a single-quote in the variable's value).

Comment: Construct cmdContrib  with a static SQL query, like you have with cmdTest, and see what happens.  The problem might jump out at you then.

Comment: folderSsystem.ContributorCodde contains 'PST'.

Comment: The debug value for folderSystem.ContributorCode is "PST".  Tried making it a static query: "SELECT ContributorId FROM tblContributor WHERE Code='PST'".  Still returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Profiler to confirm:

A) how many rows are being returned (I suspect 0)
 B) What database it is in
 C) what its login/user context is.
 D) what the actual entire SQL command is.

Extract this command and re-execute it in the same database to confirm that it does return a value.  If this suceeds, then change your execution context to that which the Profiler said that the connection was running under and try again.  If it fails now (returns 0 rows) then check to see if the source table (Contributor) may actually be a View that is implementing row-level security.

Comment: " C) what its login/user context" +1 to that, it's very easy that the app is running in a different context

Comment: It was a different database (embarrassing)  Although this answer can serve as a check list for this category of question.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to all of us sooner or later.